# Автоматическая загрузка зависимостей зависимости в Maven

Tags: java, maven

Я создаю библиотеку "А", которая импортирует зависимость "B". Когда я включил библиотеку "А" в проекте, я получаю `NoSuchMethodError` если я также явно не включил зависимость "B" в pom проекта.

При импорте зависимости "А", есть способ сказать Maven автоматически включать все его зависимости, включая "B" (без ручного импорта "B")?

pom.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

        <groupId>parking</groupId>
        <artifactId>parking</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
                <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.38</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

    </project>
```

С таким pom.xml получаю Exception:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но как только добавляю все зависимости Hibernate, все как по маслу. 
Pom.xml после добавления всех зависимостей в ручную:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>parking</groupId>
    <artifactId>parking</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml</groupId>
            <artifactId>classmate</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.b2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
            <artifactId>geronimo-jta_1.1_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.20.0-GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
            <artifactId>jandex</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.38</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Графы:

Вариант 1: С прописанными dependencies в pom:

[image: Граф 1]

Вариант 2: без прописанных dependencies в pom:

[image: Граф 2]

Comment: Maven автоматом тянет все зависимости, у вас в чем-то другом проблема. Добавьте, пожалуйста, `pom.xml` в текстовом виде и скажите как вы тесты запускаете.

Comment: @enzo переформулировал вопрос, изменил шапку, на самом деле проблема не с junit, а с Hibernate. Не могу понять как устроен Maven.

Comment: У вас в описании проблемы ClassNotFoundException, в скриншоте NoSuchMethodError. Мэйвен сам цепляет связанные зависимости и, видимо, у разных используемых библиотек слишком сильно расходятся используемые версии Hibernate. Когда вы сами явно указываете используемые библиотеки, то в classpath попадают именно они, а не зависимости зависимостей. У вас есть возможность использовать средства построения графа зависимостей, как в Enterprise версии IntelliJ Idea?

Comment: @Mark исправил, спасибо. Прикрепил графы, если я Вас правильно понял.

Comment: Не могу не отметиться комментарием (несмотря на то, что у автора вопроса проблема очевидно в другом): maven-проект (назовем его P) может помечать зависимость как опциональную, и в этом случае она не будет подтягиваться автоматом в проектах, зависящих от P.

Comment: Поздравляю, ваш первый JAR hell. Попробуйте, http://stackoverflow.com/a/32913401/5694145

Answer (score 1):

Вообщем проблема в:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

Без неё Hibernate не хотел взлетать. Но эта библиотека присутвствует, в Entity manager dependecies, то следовательно Maven должен был подтягивать и её автоматом:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

Следовательно как упомянул, товарищ enzo, это, навреное, Jar Hell.